# react-native run-android not work task:react-native-keychain:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I cloned an old repo, this currently works in third's pcs. This is made in react native.

**The problem** when I use **react-native run-android** this failed and get this message.

> Android gradle plugin: 3.6.3
> Gradle: 6.3
> building Reanimated2

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :react-native-keychain:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
> Use* '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.

also  got this message:

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up

i'm using "react-native": "0.64.2", "react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0"

and my build.grandle is

```
  buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
  minSdkVersion = 21
  compileSdkVersion = 30
  targetSdkVersion = 30
```